# General solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=1$, $(y\neq 1)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

> Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}+y=1$, $(y\neq 1)$

The general solution for this differential equation is given in my reference as $y=1+Ae^{-x}$, but is it a complete solution ?

**My Attempt**

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=1-y\implies \frac{dy}{1-y}=dx\\
\int\frac{dy}{1-y}=\int dx\implies\int\frac{dy}{y-1}=-\int dx\\
\log|y-1|=-x+C_1\implies |y-1|=e^{-x}.e^{C_1}\\
|y-1|=A.e^{-x}\\
y=\begin{cases}1+A.e^{-x};\quad y\geq1\\
1-A.e^{-x};\quad y<1
\end{cases}
$$
right ?

Comment: Use C as a constant that can be positive or negative

Comment: $y=1$ is a solution too

Comment: @Isham: this is excluded in the problem statement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes you're right..I guess they exluded it because of the method used to solve this equation ( separable equation) ...But with integrating factor that condition is not needed.

Comment: @Isham: whatever the reason, it is excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine both of these cases into

$$ y(x) = 1 + ce^{-x} $$

where $c$ can be positive or negative. Then $c = A > 0$ implies $y > 1$, and $c = -A < 0$ implies $y < 1$

Also $c=0$ includes the trivial solution $y\equiv 1$.

Comment: ohh thats right, i stuck thinking the solution must be incomplete. thnx anyways. but why the condition $y\neq 1$ ?

Comment: I believe that should be $y(x) = 1 + ce^{-x}$ (i.e., you lost the "minus" sign in the exponent).

Comment: @JohnHughes I did. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ss1729 you can see right away, without even solving, that $y=1$ is a constant solution. This makes it a trivial solution, and the problem wants you to find other solutions.

Comment: Also, if you are done with the question, make sure the "check" the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y$ is a solution. Define
$$
u(x) = y(x) - 1. 
$$
then $u'(x) = y'(x)$, so $u$ is a solution to 
$$
u(x) + u'(x) = 0
$$
Now let $v(x) = u(-x)$. Then $v'(x) = -u'(x)$, so 
$$
v(x) = v'(x).
$$
The only solution to this equation (I'm assuming you've seen this before!) is 
$$
v(x) = ce^x
$$
(for any real constant $c$). Hence $u(x) = c e^{-x}$, and $y(x) = c e^{-x} + 1$.

If you want to restrict to solutions where $y$ is not the constant function $y(x) = 1$, then you need to choose $c$ to be any nonzero real number.